# How can I get items that their names start with a number in Linq To Sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

How can I get a list of Products that, for example, theirs productName starts with a number?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

Products.Where(n => n.ProductName.SubString(0,1) >= "0" && n.ProductName.SubString(0,1) <= "9")

Comment: This doesn't appear to compile - operator >= cannot be applied to arguments of type string and string.

Comment: It works if you change Substring(0, 1) to [0] and use chars instead: `(b => b.Name[0] >= '0' && b.Name[0] <= '9'`.

Comment: I cannot use the first method as it shows we cannot apply >= to arguments of type string, but while i am trying to use second method at run time i m getting an exception as:    "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Char get_Chars(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Answer (score 5):

```
List<string> digits = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();
var query = from p in db.Products
            where digits.Contains(p.productName.Substring(0, 1))
            select p;
```

Alternatively, add the following to your DBML mapping file:

```
<Function Name="ISNUMERIC" IsComposable="true">
    <Parameter Name="Expression" Parameter="Expression" Type="System.String" DbType="NVarChar(4000)" />
    <Return Type="System.Boolean" DbType="BIT NOT NULL"/>
</Function>
```

Then you can say:

```
var query = from p in db.Products
            where db.ISNUMERIC(p.productName.Substring(0, 1))
            select p;
```

You can do this in an XML mapping file too but I can't remember the syntax off the top of my head for the necessary code in your manually defined `DataContext`. Let me know if you need this.

I strongly prefer the first method but can see using the SQL built-in `ISNUMERIC` if profiling told me the pure LINQ version is a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

`List<string> searchProducts = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0" };`

`dbContext.Products.Where(x=> searchProducts.Any(y=> x.ProductName.StartsWith(y))).ToList();`